# UnsupportedClassVersionError on JDBC Java Tutorial

Tags: java, jdbc, ant, javac, unsupported-class-version

I am having a common issue the known UnsupportedClassVersionError, i am running the JDBC Tutorial of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html , using Ant Apache, which is already configurated. I am aware of the nature of the error, but i just dont know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fix the problem, first i update my Java Version, then i use the line comand: ANT CLEAN which erase the .class files from the corresponding directory, and finally i recompile my java files with ANT JAR and VOILA!!